# Composing property wrappers in Swift with Vapor + Fluent

Tags: swift, codable, vapor, property-wrapper, vapor-fluent

I've implemented a system to automatically generate Fluent's `Migration`s by reflecting 'registered' `Model`s, saving the boilerplate of creating them manually. To achieve this, I must allow the specification of any `DatabaseSchema.FieldConstraint`s directly in the `Model`. Since I'm unable to inherit from `FieldProperty`, etc. as they're marked as `final`, this system requires that I use nested property wrappers like so:

```swift
final class User: Model {
…
    @Constrained(.required)
    @Field(key: .userForename)
    var forename: String
…
}
```

Inside the implementation of the `@Constrained` property wrapper, I have the following code:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
class ConstrainedProperty<T, U>: AnyConstrainedProperty where T: Fields, U: AnyProperty {
    // MARK: - Properties

    // MARK: Property Wrapper

    var projectedValue: ConstrainedProperty<T, U> { self }

    var wrappedValue: U

    // MARK: Stored

    var constraints: [DatabaseSchema.FieldConstraint]

    // MARK: - Initialisers

    init(wrappedValue: U, _ constraints: DatabaseSchema.FieldConstraint...) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self.constraints = constraints
    }
}

// MARK: - Fields

extension Fields {
    typealias Constrained<T> = ConstrainedProperty<Self, T> where T: Property
}
```

Since `wrappedValue` is `Optional`, `wrappedValue` never being initialised is not an issue and the code compiles just fine. However, if I want `wrappedValue` not to be `Optional` and for it to be provided a value when the property wrapper is initialised, the Swift Evolution proposal (SE-0258) states that I should use the following code:

```swift
var wrappedValue: T
var constraints: [DatabaseSchema.FieldConstraint]

init(wrappedValue: T, _ constraints: DatabaseSchema.FieldConstraint...) {
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    self.constraints = constraints
}
```

(`T` should be `FieldProperty<Model, Value>` where `Model == Self` and `Value: Codable`.)

Unfortunately, the issue is that Swift complains:
[image: 1]

It doesn't appear that Swift's passing the value of the nested property wrapper to the `wrappedValue` parameter of the initialiser of the outer property wrapper automatically — I inferred from the proposal that it should; how else would property wrapper composition work ?